# Software to help understand source code

Tags: gratis, open-source, software-development, source-code

I am looking for an open-source software that would help me understand source code faster. I am aware of tools like [Understand](https://scitools.com/), [Source Insight](http://www.sourceinsight.com/), etc., but they are commercial with hefty fees for a license.

The software should be easy to use, should provide a graphical depiction of the functions, data structures etc. and should allow me to change variable names and add comments within the software itself.

- Platform: Windows or Linux. Plugins to IDEs are also fine.
- Languages supported: C++ and Java, anything in addition to this is a plus.

The software should work well with large source codes like those of Linux.

Comment: [SonarQube](http://www.sonarqube.org/#) might also be something for you. I didn't use it much, so I haven't got enough knowledge to recommend it.

Comment: Have you tried OpenGrok? Setting it up is relatively easy. http://vineelkumarreddy.com/2015/04/29/how-to-install-opengrok-on-windows/

Comment: Just for others: [CodeScene](https://empear.com/products/codescene-on-premise/) is another commercial product. It aim is to also understand the team and the communication paths behind the code by analyzing the commit history.

Comment: https://alternativeto.net/software/understand/

Comment: looks Sourcetrail is a good alternative: https://github.com/CoatiSoftware/Sourcetrail and https://www.sourcetrail.com

Answer (score 8):

Update 2019-08-27: **this tool has reached end of life** and seems no longer maintained.

---

All in all, I'd say your wish list for a gratis tool like that is quite long. In the last company I worked for, I was responsible for the maintenance of projects and I made myself familiar with metrics and code quality analysis. Below information is given on my knowledge of ~2 years ago. The only free tool I found that roughly matches your requirements is

[ConQAT](https://www.cqse.eu/en/products/conqat/overview/), the Continuous Quality Analysis Tool.

It

- analyzes Java, C++, C#, ABAP, ADA
- is gratis ([Apache 2](https://www.cqse.eu/en/products/conqat/install/))
- integrates in Eclipse, so you can rename variables etc. as usual
- allows for analysis of architectural constraints and code clones
- works at least on Windows, not sure about Linux. It's Java-based, so it might work there as well if you don't need C# support.

Regarding

- *easy to use*: well, it depends on what "easy" means for you. The metrics are built with a GUI, so basically, yes. You should have knowledge of metrics, though.
- *graphical depiction of the functions*: not something like IDA Pro, but e.g. with treemaps. It can also visualize the architecture at least down to class level.
- *large source codes*: I have no clue how large the source code of Linux is. It worked fine on a C# project with 130k LOC

Other notes (based on information 2 years ago):

- The tool is updated in irregular intervals, although the version numbering system suggests that there are 2 releases per year.
- It's hard to get support, unless you're willing to pay for it. I did not find a "community" that would answer questions.
- You can implement own information providers in Java.

Comment: A great answer, and a great tool. Alas, after you posted this, the link now points to a blog post announcing that it is end of life :-(

Comment: @Mawg: thanks for the notice. Of course the successor, TeamScale, is no longer gratis. The source code of ConQAT should remain available under Apache2 license, but I doubt that there will be a community developing this as a Github project for example. :-(